# Android SIP / VoIP with doorbell: View video before answering

Tags: video, android, voip, sip, rtsp

I am currently using the 2N Helios IP Vario doorbell device.
It can be used via SIP protocol, but can also communicate with the 2N Android app directly, without an additional server, which I would prefer.

The 2N Android app basically works, but has many bugs yet, and no one knows if or when they are fixed. It does not make sense if you have to reboot your phone or doorbell every day, or even after every call sometimes.

As there are almost no alternative apps to use, another possibility is to use the native SIP functions in Android, e.g. with a local Asterisk server. This works better, also with the doorbell video functionality, BUT - as usual in phone calls - you see the video only AFTER you answer the bell.

The doorbell is able to provide a video or image source of the camera all the time, and can call an HTTP link when a button is pressed, so I am searching for an Android app which can do the following:

- Display an RTSP video or JPG image source when a SIP call is
  received, e.g. display it directly in the Android call window.
- Show an additional button where you can define an HTTP link which
  opens the door (for EIB/KNX server connected to door lock)

Please let me know if this is possible.
If necessary, I would code the app myself, maybe you could give me some hints how to modify the call window or handle a useful event, if this is possible (I am mainly a C# / PHP developer).

Thank you!

(I am using Android 4.2.2)

Comment: If you're going the SIP-way you should be able to open the lock via the phone-call. `Electric lock switch controlled directly from the VoIP telephone`. Now you only need a way to show the image before the call. (Maybe something as pushing the image as a contact-photo to your phone but i'm not sure it would arrive on time before the phone rings?)

Comment: I'm reading [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) SIP does support sending a photo with the INVITE. `Call-Info: <http://wwww.example.com/alice/photo.jpg> ;purpose=icon <http://www.example.com/alice/> ;purpose=info`. So maybe that something to look into. (search for photo in the `rfc3261.txt`)

Comment: I think Asterisk supports it too with the `SIPAddHeader()`. (e.g. `SIPAddHeader(Call-Info: <http://hostname.com/pics/face-b64.bmp>\;purpose=icon)`). Now you need to see if your SIP-client on the phone supports it and setup your Asterisk server to get the image before setting the call through).

Comment: I think this could be the right direction, hopefully the client will support it. Will try this in the next few days and give you information, thank you.

Comment: I tried to add the `SIPAddHeader()` to my Asterisk setup here and it **does** send out the `Call-Info`-line. But none of my apps on my Galaxy S2 use this header. (`SipDroid`, `CSipSimple`, `Zoiper`.) I would have thought they would have implemented this because it seems like a nice feature. Maybe you have better luck. Otherwise you would have to use the source of `CSipSimple` and code it in yourself. (Not an easy thing to do.) I know these [snom Voip Phones](http://www.snom.com/en/products/ip-phones/snom-821/) accept a picture. See [here](https://forum.snom.com/index.php?showtopic=9050).

Comment: Thank you for testing, did you also try the native SIP Client? (Should be somewhere under call settings, internet call accounts) It would be a pity if this feature was not implemented on any Android client yet...

Comment: Yep. Samsung's own Android doesn't have SIP in Europe but luckily i run CyanogenMod (which does). But unfortunately also the native SIP client doesn't give the picture. I tried `.jpg`, `.gif` and finally monochroom `.bmp`. None give the picture. I think we stumbled upon a seldom used feature only some hard-phones with display use. Even the soft-phones for Windows i tried do not give a picture. The code of CSipSimple and SipDroid are open (and many forks exist) but i think it would take some digging to modify the source.

Comment: I posted a suggestion on the Csipsimple and Sipdroid sites, and had a quick look at the Sipdroid code. Maybe [this](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/phone/CallerInfo.java) could be interesting: "public Drawable cachedPhoto;". I will try to modify it when I have some time left, so the cachedPhoto would be loaded from an URL.

Comment: I think you need to look at `photoResource` and where it is assigned. I couldn't find it comes from `Call-Info`. I think it uses the internal contacts and takes a contact-photo from there. But maybe it can be changed so it takes the URL from the `Call-Info` and subsequently downloads the photo from that info. (The protocol is `Call-Info: <url_of_photo> ;purpose=icon`).

Comment: You can see the `PhotoResource` in the [CallCard.java](https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/phone/CallCard.java). That points to `call.getEarliestConnection` which should be the INVITE-code. Haven't looked any deeper than that ;)

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343597/how-to-correctly-get-photo-of-contact) (the `CONTENT_URI`). That's the way to get the photo from the contact. You can see in [ContactsAsyncHelper.java](https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/phone/ContactsAsyncHelper.java) at line 156 `getPhotoUri` where it gets the photo from the Google-contact. You could change it there.

Comment: Thank you for all your help yet. Are you using Asterisk with FreePBX? As I am quite new to Asterisk, I only found out I have to add the SipAddHeader() command to extensions_custom.conf, but have not found out the exact syntax to use..

Comment: I'm using Asterisk. I haven't converted to FreePBX yet. Was planning to look at it in the future though. For Asterisk i used [this](http://pastebin.com/L96JFLVX). I used a portable version of [PhonerLite](http://portableapps.com/node/21402) to look at the debug information if it got the `Call-Info`-line (and i did). You could of course use your own soft-phone to look at the debug information.

Comment: Come to think of it... :( With SipDroid i never get an image even when calling from a phone which number is registered with a contact (http://i.imgur.com/CwfqqmS.png). But according to the source it should work. Weird. CSipSimple does give me a image (at ring it's the top half of the screen and after answering the full screen).

Comment: Finally I got SipAddHeader working with FreePBX by inserting [this](http://pastebin.com/fp8HLjEG) into extensions_custom.conf. The image is shown on a Snom 760 device, like you described. Csipsimple also seems [interested](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=2563&q=http%20image) that they add such a feature. Anyway, I will try to compile a modified version in the next few days.

Comment: I was now able to modify the CSipSimple .apk to show the image of the doorbell (hard-coded link at the moment, but it works). If the CSipSimple team allows me to publish the modified file, I will post it here. Thank you Rik for your help!